# is it possible to discard duplicate frames in a video?

Tags: framerate

I have a 2 minute game capture that ranges from 60fps to 2fps but the capture is in 30fps. is there any way to discard the duplicate frames so that the video looks smooth? I was thinking of extracting every frame and discarding duplicate frames but that sounds like effort.

Answer (score 1):

[mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) - Drop frames that do not differ greatly from the previous frame in order to reduce frame rate. Therefore, the command would be

```
ffmpeg -i canada_6.mp4 -vf mpdecimate out.ts
```